# soap header authentication

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, soap

how can I make use of credentials in a soap header? I know how to set them:

```
BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) coreWebService;
bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "username");
bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "password");
```

But how can I verify them on the webservice side? How can I "extract" them from the request that is send by a client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the code you posted puts the credentials into the HTTP header, not the SOAP header.

You should be able to access what you need from the WebServiceContext.

For SOAP headers:

http://metro.java.net/guide/ch04.html#accessing-soap-headers-for-incoming-messages

HTTP headers:

http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=351

Answer (score 0):

Set up [basic authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) on your server. You can check the headers (by sniffing traffic) and see that that your request will contain an `Authorization` header with some Base64 encoded content containing your username and password.

Answer (score 0):

me funciono asi:

> ```
> BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) port;
> Map<String, Object> map = bp.getRequestContext();
> map.put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "aspbbo");
> map.put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "dkN6ssP");
>
>
> Map<String, List<String>> credentials = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
> credentials.put("username", Collections.singletonList("aspbbo"));
> credentials.put("password", Collections.singletonList("dkN6ssP"));
> ((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, credentials);
> ```

Comment: This site is using English only, you cannot expect someone to be able to read every language.